# How to delete GIT repo in TFS 2015

Tags: git, tfs, tfs-2015, tfvc

When we first created some team projects we choose Git for the Source Control. The teams want to switch to TFVC. TFS 2015 update 1 and above support both Git and TFVC in the same project.

My question is, we don't have anything in the Git Repository. I would like to delete it so that the end users don't even see it since we are not using it.

How do I delete the Git Repositories option.  I don't want it showing up in the WEB UI or Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one Git repository, you can't delete it. That may have changed in later versions of TFS, but in TFS 2015, that was how it was.

You can set the repo's security so that no one can access it, which may hide it.

Comment: Even though I created a TFVC repo instead, it wont let me delete the only Git repo?  I guess I can live with setting it to read only or no access

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, seems you want to remove unused Git repos from your team project when they are no longer needed.

For **multiple** repos:

1. Select the settings icon in the web to bring up the project administration page and choose **Version Control**.
   [image]
2. Select the Git repository to remove from the list shown and select
   the ... next to the name. Choose **Delete Repository**.

   [image]

For **single** repo:

> You cannot remove a repo if it is the only Git repo in the Project. If
>   you need to delete the only Git repo in a Project, **create a new Git
>   repo** first, then delete the repo.

As a workaround you could set the single git repo's permission Ready to Deny for contributors groups.

[image]